# Можно ли сделать такое в svg?

Tags: html, css3, html5, svg

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли сделать такой border в svg, как лучше сделать, охота еще сделать анимацию крутящуюся?

Comment: Эльдар, посмотрите на сайте [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/), по данной ссылке пример №5 скорее всего есть то, что вам надо.

Comment: Можно прямую ссылку?

Comment: Это и есть прямая ссылка на ту статью, просто она отформатированна,  пример находится на этой странице, ниже

Answer (score 2):

```html
<style>
 #r1 {
background: linear-gradient(45deg, #F7F3F7, #C5DDE8);
}
</style> 
<div id="r1">
 <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 400 400" >
 <rect  x="10" y="10" width="200" height="350" stroke-width="3" stroke-dashoffset="5" stroke-dasharray="10 10" fill="none" stroke="#7D7798" />
</svg> 
</div>
```

### Анимация SVG

```html
<style>
 #r1 {
background: linear-gradient(45deg, #F7F3F7, #C5DDE8);
}
</style> 
<div id="r1">
 <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 400 400" >
 <rect  x="10" y="10" width="200" height="350" stroke-width="3" stroke-dashoffset="5" stroke-dasharray="10 10" fill="none" stroke="#7D7798" >
 <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="550;0;550" dur="8s" fill="freeze" />
 </rect>
</svg>  
</div>
```

### Анимация CSS

```css
 .container{
 width:300;
 height:350;
 
background: linear-gradient(90deg, #F7F3F7, #C5DDE8);
}


#r1:hover  { 
fill:#C4DCF0;
stroke:#7D7798; 
stroke-dasharray: 1150;
stroke-dashoffset: 1150;
-webkit-animation: draw1 3s  ease-in-out forwards; 
animation: draw1 3s ease-in-out forwards;



}
#r1 {
fill:#DCE7F0;
stroke:#C0C2DB;
}
@keyframes draw1 {
  0% { stroke-dasharray:20 10; stroke-dashoffset:1150;}
  100% { stroke-dasharray:20 10; stroke-dashoffset:550;}
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container" >
 <svg   width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 400 400" >
  <g id="r1">
 <rect  x="10" y="10" width="200" height="350" stroke-width="3"  />
 <text font-size="36" font-family="sans-serif" x="35" y="120" stroke="#7D7798" font-weight="500">Over me</text>
 </g>
</svg>  
</div>
```